# Ubuntu Trickle Will Not Open Chrome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, throttling

I'm trying to open Chrome with trickle to throttle the upload speed so I can test a sites image uploading progress display, but the build in dev tools for chrome only allow throttling for downloads. This command works for Firefox, but Chrome's dev tools are just so far beyond what Firefox has to offer. Here's what I'm using now, which just leaves me with a blank terminal

```
trickle -s -d 256 -w 512 google-chrome-unstable
```

I've tried the stable version as well, but neither seem to be working.

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  On Fedora 22, trickle works with firefox but not with chrome.  However, chrome dev tools now include download throttling which may or may not help you.

Comment: Nope, I need to throttle the upload speed to test my progress loaders, but it's quite difficult over a local site, since the upload is near instant.